# how to serialize or dump a variable in R? or how to find this answer

Tags: r, serialization, dump

I just wanted to save a smallish R object that took a long time to make into a variable assignment in an Rmd file. I remembered there was some very simple command in base R, but I couldn't remember the name. Here are a few of the Google searches I tried:

- r serialize object
- r object to string
- r object to dump

I finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018480/what-is-the-equivalent-of-var-dump-in-r) -- **dput**!!

My question, which probably isn't appropriate for SO, is: when thing comes up next time and I start searching and find `serialize` and `dump` and who knows what else, is there some place to find an overview of the different options and why to use one or the other?

Maybe someone could update [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018480/what-is-the-equivalent-of-var-dump-in-r) from eight years ago and add 'dump' and 'serialize' to the keywords and title?

Comment: Relevant post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370132/r-data-formats-rdata-rda-rds-etc

Comment: You can also suggest an edit in that linked post.